# How to create a reeder-like / iOS mail list programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for a way to create programmatically a reeder-like list (like here http://reederapp.com/mac/_screens/img/2.png - the list with the article's summary). What is the kind of element used? Is there any example that shows how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you talking about the list on the left or the list in the middle?  Do you want to do it on iOS or on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

That's just an [`NSTableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The easiest way to create it would be to use the new view-based table view introduced in Lion. That way you can lay out the table cells in the Xcode XIB editor.